# Section Header Collectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, header

I have tried to add a section header to my grid collectionview but I keep getting this error.

```
Thread 1: "the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: for element kind 'UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter' at index path <NSIndexPath: 0xfa8d71d0dca3589b> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}; supplementary view: <UICollectionReusableView: 0x7fba7296bdc0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x6000013f48a0>>"
```

**My SectionHeader**

```
    class SectionHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
        
        var label: UILabel = {
            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.textColor = KSColor.neutral400.getColor()
            label.lineSpacing =  -0.12
            label.font = .sfProTextMedium(size: 12)
            label.sizeToFit()
            return label
        }()
        
        // MARK: Object lifecycle
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
                super.init(frame: frame)
    
                addSubview(label)
    
                label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
                label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
                label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
                label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
           }
    
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
            }
    }
```

**My collectionview controller**

```
    class SelfServiceCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    
     func setUpCollectionView() {
            gridCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "EmptyCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "emptyCell")
            gridCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SelfServiceRootCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "selfServiceRootCell")
            gridCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "SelfServiceChildCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "selfServiceChildCell")
            gridCollectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
    }
    
     // MARK: Header
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
            if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
                let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeader
                sectionHeader.label.text = parentVC.selfServiceArray[indexPath.section].categoryName.uppercased()
                return sectionHeader
            } else {
                return UICollectionReusableView()
            }
        }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
            if parentVC.selfServiceArray.isEmpty {
                return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
            } else {
                if parentVC.selfServiceArray[section].categoryName == "" {
                    return CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
                } else {
                    return CGSize(width: 250, height: 50)
                }
            }
        }
```

When I remove

```
if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
```

from code I get this error instead of previous one

```
Thread 1: "could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier header - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"
```

I did not create a nib file for it. Why does it need it? I am adding label programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I registered both header and footer

```
gridCollectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
        gridCollectionView.register(SectionHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
```

then separated kind to a switch case as below

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
            let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeader
            sectionHeader.label.text = parentVC.selfServiceArray[indexPath.section].categoryName.uppercased()
            return sectionHeader
        case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:
            let sectionFooter = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! SectionHeader
            sectionFooter.label.text = ""
            return sectionFooter
        default:
                assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }
```

worked